# Use tkinter loop to make similar widgets with different outputs

Tags: python, tkinter, lambda

I'm trying to make a loop for adding widgets.
The code is supposed to add 5 buttons, each button giving a different number when pressed.

```
import tkinter as tk
top = tk.Tk()
m1 =tk.Frame(width=400, height=400)
m1.pack()


def thingie(s):
    
    print(s)

for i in range(5):

    btn = tk.Button(m1, text='Button'+str(i), command=lambda:thingie(i))
    btn.place(x=0, y=i*35)

top.mainloop()
```

The code runs with no errors, but each button gives me the same number instead of different numbers. How do I fix this?

Comment: you could use `functools.partial` instead of `lambda`

Comment: @quikerwick. It worked for me. There is nothing wrong with the code.. I got different numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import tkinter as tk
top = tk.Tk()
m1 =tk.Frame(width=400, height=400)
m1.pack()


def thingie(s):
    print(s)


for i in range(5):
    btn = tk.Button(m1, text='Button'+str(i), command=lambda m=i: thingie(m))
    btn.place(x=0, y=i*35)

top.mainloop()
```